# Set-ClusterQuorum: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'

Tags: windows, powershell, failovercluster

I am trying to add fileshare witness in windows server 2016 by executing this command.
**
Set-ClusterQuorum -FileShareWitness \SQL-DR\Witness -Credential (Get-Credential)**

But every time i try to execute this command it gives me this error

**Set-ClusterQuorum: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'.**

I have even updated PowerShell version to 7.3.6, but error still exist .... what might be possible solution.

I have even updated PowerShell version to 7.3.6, but error still exist .... what might be possible solution.